# Explicação sobre tags dos componentes do Android

Tags: java, android, view

Estou desenvolvendo um *app* para *Android*. Encontrei alguns tutoriais para me ajudar no desenvolvimento porém  encontrei algumas *tags* que não entendi suas devidas explicações e quando devo usar  cada uma delas.

São elas:

- **Thread**
- **SurfaceView**
- **Surface holder**
- **Holder**

Já pesquisei em vários lugares na internet, comprei um livro de *Android* mas ainda não entendi direito. Podem me ajudar?

Obrigado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estas tags que você está com dúvida é o que chamamos de componentes no Android.

Elas ajudam na hora da criação de um projeto,então vou explicar resumido sobre cada uma.

**Thread :**

Quando um aplicativo é iniciado e este aplicativo não tem quaisquer outros componentes em execução,o sistema Android inicia um novo processo Linux para a aplicação com um único thread de execução.Por padrão todos os componentes do mesmo aplicativo funcionam em um mesmo thread.

Quando uma aplicação é iniciada, o sistema cria um thread de execução para o aplicativo, chamado de "principal". Este thread é muito importante, pois é responsável por despachar eventos para os widgets de interface do usuário apropriadamente, incluindo eventos de desenho. Ele também é o segmento em que seu aplicativo interage com componentes do kit de ferramentas UI Android (componentes dos pacotes android.widget e android.view). Como tal, o thread principal também é às vezes chamado de segmento.Por padrão todos componentes seguem o mesmo thread.

Para melhores informações olhe aqui na documentação sobre :

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

**SurfaceView :**

Fornece uma superfície de desenho dedicado incorporado dentro de uma hierarquia de vista. Você pode controlar o formato dessa superfície e, se quiser, o seu tamanho; o SurfaceView cuida de colocar a superfície no local correto na tela.

Para melhores informações olhe aqui na documentação sobre :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

**Surface :**

A superfície é um objeto segurando pixels que estão sendo compostas para a tela. Cada janela que você vê na tela (uma caixa de diálogo, sua atividade de tela cheia, a barra de status) tem a sua própria superfície que ele desenha-se para o Surface Flinger(responsável pela composição de todas superfícies de aplicativos e sistemas em um único buffer) e torna eles para a exibição final em sua Z-ordem correta. Uma superfície normalmente tem mais de um tampão (normalmente dois) para fazer a renderização.

Para melhores informações olhe aqui na documentação sobre :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html

**Surface Holder :**

Interface abstrata para alguém segurando uma superfície de exibição. Permite-lhe controlar o tamanho e formato de superfícies, editar os pixels na superfície, e monitorar alterações na superfície. Esta interface é normalmente disponível através da classe SurfaceView.

Para melhores informações olhe aqui na documentação sobre :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html

Pesquise mais sobre estes componentes,pois são importantes para quando você quer se aprofundar na questão de entender melhor o Android.Geralmente dar uma olhada na documentação deles e pesquisar mais afundo,pode sanar estas suas dúvidas.